# How to find out what class/function has invoked extension hook?

Tags: add-on-development, php, extension

I have an extension that relies on certain extension hook.

The hook can be invoked either by function from EE core or third-party module.

I need to be able to tell what function / class has invoked it. Is there a way I can find that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should loop through the output of PHP's [debug_backtrace() method](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php).

For example, I just called it inside an extension using the `channel_entries_query_result` hook (truncated a little). The `object` or `class` parameters would be most helpful to you to figure out which extension called the hook:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [function] => channel_entries_query_result
            [class] => Store_ext
            [object] => Store_ext Object
            [type] => ->
            [args] => Array
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [file] => /path/to/system/expressionengine/libraries/Extensions.php
            [line] => 241
            [function] => call_user_func_array
            [args] => Array
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [function] => universal_call
            [class] => EE_Extensions
            [object] => EE_Extensions Object
            [type] => ->
            [args] => Array
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [file] => /path/to/system/expressionengine/libraries/Extensions.php
            [line] => 119
            [function] => call_user_func_array
            [args] => Array
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [file] => /path/to/system/expressionengine/modules/channel/mod.channel.php
            [line] => 3315
            [function] => call
            [class] => EE_Extensions
            [object] => EE_Extensions Object
            [type] => ->
            [args] => Array
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [file] => /path/to/system/expressionengine/modules/channel/mod.channel.php
            [line] => 324
            [function] => parse_channel_entries
            [class] => Channel
            [object] => Channel Object
            [type] => ->
            [args] => Array
        )
)
```